# How to mock child function with Jest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a sendMail.js class content as below

```
export default function registerEmailHandlers() {
  const sendMailAsync = async (emailAddress) => {
    return await sendMail();
  }
  return {
    sendMailAsync
  }
}
```

How can I write Jest mock for this type of code?
I want mock sendMailAsync always return 'some test'.
I tried to research but nothing same that what I want.

Comment: I don't think it's doable unless you move your function out. Not sure why you're keen to mock it if you have to test entire function though

Comment: because i don't want to call API to send mail in my test.

Comment: If so, any reason why don't you move that function out for being easier to mock?

Comment: I don't know why my team is choosen this style of code. It make me hard to mock the function inside. Is there any best practice when write js function here?

Comment: Or you can mock the `sendMail` (I suppose it's from a different module or in a different scope which can be mocked) which is being used inside in your scope function also is not a bad idea.

Comment: If you mock sendMailAsync, what's left that you're actually testing? Mock the *collaborator*, sendMail.

Comment: You should not mock `sendMailAsync`, which is an implementation detail. You should mock either `sendMail` or the whole `registerEmailHandlers` (having it return a different object).

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like

```js
const mockSendMailAsync = jest.fn());

jest.mock('./path/to/file/sendMail', () => (
    sendMailAsync = mockSendMailAsync
)
```

Then you could assert that mockSendMailAsync has been called